# How to list all methods for an object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I list all the methods that a particular object has access to?

I have a `@current_user` object, defined in the application controller:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

And want to see what methods I have available to me in the view file. Specifically, I want to see what methods a `:has_many` association provides. (I know what `:has_many` *should* provide, but want to check that.)

Comment: To clarify, you want the methods callable on `@current_user`?

Comment: @Dirk, welcome to stackoverflow! Remember to "check" the answer that best answers your question. Also upvote any answer, to any question, that you find useful/helpful.

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many

Answer (score 277, accepted):

The following will list the methods that the User class has that the base Object class does not have...

```
>> User.methods - Object.methods
=> ["field_types", "maximum", "create!", "active_connections", "to_dropdown",
    "content_columns", "su_pw?", "default_timezone", "encode_quoted_value", 
    "reloadable?", "update", "reset_sequence_name", "default_timezone=", 
    "validate_find_options", "find_on_conditions_without_deprecation", 
    "validates_size_of", "execute_simple_calculation", "attr_protected", 
    "reflections", "table_name_prefix", ...
```

Note that `methods` is a method for Classes and for Class instances.

Here's the methods that my User class has that are not in the ActiveRecord base class:

```
>> User.methods - ActiveRecord::Base.methods
=> ["field_types", "su_pw?", "set_login_attr", "create_user_and_conf_user", 
    "original_table_name", "field_type", "authenticate", "set_default_order",
    "id_name?", "id_name_column", "original_locking_column", "default_order",
    "subclass_associations",  ... 
# I ran the statements in the console.
```

Note that the methods created as a result of the (many) has_many relationships defined in the User class are **not** in the results of the `methods` call.

**Added** Note that :has_many does not add methods directly. Instead, the ActiveRecord machinery uses the Ruby `method_missing` and `responds_to` techniques to handle method calls on the fly. As a result, the methods are not listed in the `methods` method result.

Comment: Although that may not be complete since some methods  are only created when method_missing is called (eg dynamic finders)

Comment: if I try responds_to? I get a method missing error. I'm running this inside application.html.erb

Comment: @Dirk -- maybe the method is not present...I suggest you file a new question where you show what your AR Class definitions are and then ask about the specific methods that you think :has_many should provide. Also do you have the matching :belongs_to? Rails's capitalization and pluralization rules for AR have led many astray...

Comment: @Larry. Thanks - I can get a list with .to_yaml. It looks like this: --- - :sketches - :sketch_ids - :sketches= - :sketch_ids= - :before_add_for_sketches - :before_add_for_sketches?  <many omitted>........how do I access those methods? (pointing me to documentation appreciated too :)

Comment: The [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference) for :has_many shows many of the methods that are added. Others are new for later versions of Rails. These include the "before_add_for" etc. They are "Association Callbacks" -- see that part of this [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: I like to add a (.sort) on the end to see alphabetized results array      
(User.methods.sort - Object.methods)

Comment: Do this ```methods = (User.methods - Object.methods)``` to put it into an array and then you can do ```methods.include?("method_name")```

Comment: @LarryK Hi, is there any shortcut way to list methods added by specific gem on any object any ?

Comment: Try getting the method list before and after adding the specific gem to see what changed

Answer (score 42):

Or just `User.methods(false)` to return only the methods defined within that class.

Answer (score 15):

[Module#instance_methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods)

> Returns an array containing the names of the public and protected instance methods in the receiver. For a module, these are the public and protected methods; for a class, they are the instance (not singleton) methods. With no argument, or with an argument that is false, the instance methods in mod are returned, otherwise the methods in mod and mod’s superclasses are returned.

```
module A
  def method1()  end
end
class B
  def method2()  end
end
class C < B
  def method3()  end
end

A.instance_methods                #=> [:method1]
B.instance_methods(false)         #=> [:method2]
C.instance_methods(false)         #=> [:method3]
C.instance_methods(true).length   #=> 43
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do

```
current_user.methods
```

For better listing

```
puts "\n\current_user.methods : "+ current_user.methods.sort.join("\n").to_s+"\n\n"
```

Answer (score 4):

What about one of these?

```
object.methods.sort
Class.methods.sort
```

Answer (score 4):

If You are looking list of methods which respond by an instance (in your case @current_user). According to ruby documentation [methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-methods)

> Returns a list of the names of public and protected methods of obj.
>   This will include all the methods accessible in obj's ancestors. If
>   the optional parameter is false, it returns an array of obj's
>   public and protected singleton methods, the array will not include
>   methods in modules included in obj.

```
@current_user.methods
@current_user.methods(false) #only public and protected singleton methods and also array will not include methods in modules included in @current_user class or parent of it.
```

Alternatively, You can also check that a method is callable on an object or not?.

```
@current_user.respond_to?:your_method_name
```

If you don't want parent class methods then just subtract the parent class methods from it.

```
@current_user.methods - @current_user.class.superclass.new.methods #methods that are available to @current_user instance.
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose User has_many Posts:

```
u = User.first
u.posts.methods
u.posts.methods - Object.methods
```

Answer (score 1):

To expound upon @clyfe's answer. You can get a list of your instance methods using the following code (assuming that you have an Object Class named "Parser"):

```
Parser.new.methods - Object.new.methods
```