# Rails 4 will paginate ancestors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, will-paginate

I'm using the will_paginate gem in my Rails 4 project. When I view the ancestors of the object returned from calling `paginate()`, I thought I would see something related to will_paginate in the list of ancestors, for example, maybe `WillPaginate::Collection`, but I don't see anything like this. I'm confused how my object is gaining methods like `current_page` and `total_pages`, if will_paginate doesn't appear anywhere in the ancestry tree.

For example:

```
location = Location.first
reviews = location.location_reviews.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 5)

reviews.next_page # => 2
reviews.total_pages # => 16
reviews.total_entires # => 80
```

However, the output of `reviews.ancestors` is:

```
[LocationReview(id: integer, title: string), LocationReview::GeneratedAssociationMethods, #<#<Class:0x007fd6623bec38>:0x007fd6623beda0>, ActiveRecord::Base, GlobalID::Identification, ActiveRecord::Store, ActiveRecord::Serialization, ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml, ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON, ActiveModel::Serialization, ActiveRecord::Reflection, ActiveRecord::NoTouching, ActiveRecord::Transactions, ActiveRecord::Aggregations, ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes, ActiveRecord::AutosaveAssociation, ActiveModel::SecurePassword, ActiveRecord::Associations, ActiveRecord::Timestamp, ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks, ActiveRecord::Callbacks, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Serialization, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Dirty, ActiveModel::Dirty, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::PrimaryKey, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Query, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::BeforeTypeCast, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Write, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Read, ActiveRecord::Base::GeneratedAssociationMethods, #<#<Class:0x007fd661d14e28>:0x007fd661d14ef0>, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods, ActiveModel::AttributeMethods, ActiveRecord::Locking::Pessimistic, ActiveRecord::Locking::Optimistic, ActiveRecord::AttributeDecorators, ActiveRecord::Attributes, ActiveRecord::CounterCache, ActiveRecord::Validations, ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods, ActiveSupport::Callbacks, ActiveModel::Validations, ActiveRecord::Integration, ActiveModel::Conversion, ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignment, ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection, ActiveRecord::Sanitization, ActiveRecord::Scoping::Named, ActiveRecord::Scoping::Default, ActiveRecord::Scoping, ActiveRecord::Inheritance, ActiveRecord::ModelSchema, ActiveRecord::ReadonlyAttributes, ActiveRecord::Persistence, ActiveRecord::Core, Object, ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable, PP::ObjectMixin, JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Why isn't there a class related to will_paginate in this output?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `.paginate` method on `location.location_reviews` which is the collection here. According to [this line](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/74a6cd0197072903cd8b83744133744ff4b4c046/lib/will_paginate/array.rb#L16) and [this line](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/74a6cd0197072903cd8b83744133744ff4b4c046/lib/will_paginate/array.rb#L30) of the source code of `paginate` method, seems like the `paginate` method returns the original collection after applying the options (e.g. `per_page`) on that.

So, I think it's normal behaviour in your case that `location.location_reviews.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 5)` will return an object of `location.location_reviews.class` class.

`paginate` will return whatever https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/74a6cd0197072903cd8b83744133744ff4b4c046/lib/will_paginate/array.rb#L30 will return, and `pager.replace` method is defined here: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/74a6cd0197072903cd8b83744133744ff4b4c046/lib/will_paginate/collection.rb#L112-L134
which returns the original collection type object. This proves that the behavior you see is correct.

Comment: But `reviews.class` returns `LocationReview::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`. Shouldn't it return `WillPaginate::Collection`?

Comment: If you see this line of code: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/74a6cd0197072903cd8b83744133744ff4b4c046/lib/will_paginate/array.rb#L16
when it calls `arr.paginate` it returns an array after applying the paginate options e.g. per_page, page etc. So, in your case, it should return an object of class  `location.location_reviews` which is what you are getting and is the normal behaviour.

Comment: This line actually confirms that, it returns the original collection: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/74a6cd0197072903cd8b83744133744ff4b4c046/lib/will_paginate/array.rb#L30 But, not a `WillPaginate::Collection`

Comment: I'm still confused. The comments in the link you provided say: "The result is a WillPaginate::Collection instance, which is an array with a few more properties about its paginated state." So it still sounds like it should be returning a  `WillPaginate::Collection`. I also don't understand how all of these methods can be injected into the regular behavior of an ActiveRecord collection without seeing something related to will_paginate in the ancestry chain. I am pretty new to Ruby and Rails if you couldn't tell.

Comment: It's true that the comment is a bit confusing, but the examples here: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/74a6cd0197072903cd8b83744133744ff4b4c046/lib/will_paginate/array.rb#L16-L19 make it clear that it returns the original collection type object. Also, your findings (`reviews.class returns LocationReview::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`) support that.

Comment: So, it's fine, but to know more details about how exactly it returns the original collection type object, one would need to dig deeper the gem's code base e.g. how this line works: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/74a6cd0197072903cd8b83744133744ff4b4c046/lib/will_paginate/array.rb#L30

Comment: But doesn't the fact that `LocationReview::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` responds to the `paginate` method mean that it must have been included by some module related to will_paginate? How else would the `paginate` method even exist on the collection? It doesn't exist on the object by default: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html

Comment: Okay, so `paginate` will return whatever https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/74a6cd0197072903cd8b83744133744ff4b4c046/lib/will_paginate/array.rb#L30 will return, right?  and `pager.replace` method is defined here: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/74a6cd0197072903cd8b83744133744ff4b4c046/lib/will_paginate/collection.rb#L112-L134
which returns the original collection. This proves that the behavior you see is correct even though you don't see it in the ancestor chain. There must be some Ruby magic going on.

Comment: Also, try to print this: `location.location_reviews.instance_methods` which should list all the instance_methods for `location.location_reviews` object, see if you find `paginate` there. Also see this to get some help on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595184/how-to-list-all-methods-for-an-object-in-ruby

Comment: I agree it's working correctly. The Ruby magic you're referring to is what I'm trying to understand. I do NOT see `paginate` anywhere in the output of `location.location_reviews.instance_methods` or `location.location_reviews.paginate(page: 1).instance_methods`. Even more confused now.

Comment: Can you try this: `reviews.method(:next_page).source_location`? this should give you the location of the `next_page` method.

Comment: Also, try this: `location.location_reviews.method(:paginate).source_location`.