# How to list all the methods defined in top self Object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby we have simple ways to get all the local variables, global variables with `local_variables` and `global_variables` method.

We can list the constants with Object.constants

But is there a builtin way to list all the Object methods?

Something like this:

```
def foo() end
def bar() end
def baz() end

# As `Array.new.methods' or `Array.instance_methods` returns all the methods of an Array object...

# Code to return all the methods defined above    # => [:foo, :bar, :baz]
```

In IRB, I can write:

```
def foo() end
p [self.methods.include?(:foo), self.respond_to?(:foo)]
```

And the output is `[true, true]` in IRB, but in a file, the output to standard output is `[false, false]`

Similarly if I run the following code:

```
def foo() end
puts Object.new.methods.include?(:foo)
```

In IRB, I get `true`, and if it's saved in a file, I get `false`

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595184/how-to-list-all-methods-for-an-object-in-ruby) which didn't help much:

[How to list all methods for an object in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595184/how-to-list-all-methods-for-an-object-in-ruby)

Just because it talks about getting methods of a class or a module. But I want to list the methods defined in the top self object.

Comment: Because that talks about a User class, and I want to get all the instance method of the object, just like the above example...

Comment: `SomeClass = Class.new { def foo; end; }` then `SomeClass.new.methods - Object.new.methods # => [:foo]`

Comment: @Surya, thanks for the valuable comment, but it actually creates a class. I don't want that. I want to list all the methods defined in top self object! You can simply list methods of a class with: `SomeClass = Class.new { def foo() end }.tap { |c| p c.instance_methods(false) }`, you get
`[:foo]    # => SomeClass`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest I could find is to call [`private_methods`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.2/Object.html#method-i-private_methods) on  the `main` object, with `false` as argument

> Returns the list of private methods accessible to obj. If the all
>   parameter is set to false, only those methods in the receiver will be
>   listed.

```
def foo
  "foo"
end

def bar
  "bar"
end

def baz
  "baz"
end

p private_methods(false)
# [:include, :using, :public, :private, :define_method, :DelegateClass, :foo, :bar, :baz]
```

If you omit the argument, you also get all the private methods defined in [`Kernel`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html) or [`BasicObject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html).

In order to refine the list further, you could select the methods defined for `Object`:

```
p private_methods(false).select{|m| method(m).owner == Object}
#=> [:DelegateClass, :foo, :bar, :baz]
```

Only [`:DelegateClass`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Delegator.html) is left, because it is defined in the top-level scope, just like `:foo`, `:bar` and `:baz`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works if you delete [:using, :define_method, :private, :public, :include, :DelegateClass] from the array!

`private_methods(false) - [:using, :define_method, :private, :public, :include, :DelegateClass]` ... But may the RUBY_VERSION matter? I think I shouldn't hard code it like this!!

Comment: @S.Goswami: Or `private_methods(false).select{|m| method(m).owner == Object}`. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting `false` because methods defined in the top level context are private by default.

```
def foo; end

p self.private_methods.include?(:foo)
# => true
```

I'm not sure if this is documented anywhere.

In order to get all methods, including private ones, you'll need to do e.g.:

```
all_methods = self.methods | self.private_methods
```

Try it on repl.it: https://repl.it/@jrunning/DutifulPolishedCell